# NUnit 3 and NET 4.5.1

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I've tried to migrate my project from NUnit 2.6.4 to 3.0.0 and faced an issue with .NET framework version selection.

Like in 2.6.4, I use `--framework=net-4.5.1` and get the error message:

```
The requested framework net-4.5.1 is unknown or not available.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the --framework=net-4.5.1 command line option and let NUnit 3 figure out by itself whether to run tests on the .NET Framework 2 or the .NET Framework 4 runtime.